# TLoginCredentialService usage example

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

The [documentation page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TLoginCredentialService) of this new class - introduced in XE2 - only contains references to the TObject documentation, or placeholders. I can see that this class offers a RegisterLoginHandler method, and a UnRegisterLoginHandler method, which use a [TLoginCredentialEvent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TLoginCredentialService.TLoginCredentialEvent) class. And this uses a [TLoginEvent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DBCommonTypes.TLoginEvent) object with username and password.

How would the typical use case of this class look like (source code)? Is it used somewhere in the Delphi Datasnap/Web services libraries?

Comment: You can see the updated online help here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Classes.TLoginCredentialService

Comment: @Johan That documentation is also mostly empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just created a small demo of how to use it

Click [here](http://Borrisholt.dk//TLoginCredentialService.zip) to download the code

In the following I'll show some of the code:

First I need a record to hold Credentials, and a list of them :

```
Type
  TCredential = record
    Username, Password, Domain: string;
    constructor Create(const aUsername, aPassword, aDomain: string);
    function AreEqual(const aUsername, aPassword, aDomain: string): Boolean;
  end;

  TCredentialList = class(TList<TCredential>)
  public
    function IsValidCredential(const aUsername, aPassword, aDomain: string): Boolean;
  end;
```

then we need to define a context in wich we are calling this. Thats just a application unique string wich identifyes each Loginfunction

```
const
  Context = 'TForm1';
```

In Form create I create my list and add dummy data to it

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CredentialList := TCredentialList.Create;
  //Add Dummy data
  CredentialList.Add(TCredential.Create('AA', 'AA', 'DomainAA'));
  CredentialList.Add(TCredential.Create('BB', 'BB', 'DomainAA'));
  CredentialList.Add(TCredential.Create('CC', 'CC', 'DomainAA'));

  // Register your Login handler in a context.
  // This method is called when you try to login
  // by caling TLoginCredentialService.GetLoginCredentials();
  TLoginCredentialService.RegisterLoginHandler(Context, LoginCredentialEvent);
end;
```

I have placed a button on my form from wich I make my call to login :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // The actual call to login
  // First param is the context
  // Second Parameres is a callback function given to the event handler.
  TLoginCredentialService.GetLoginCredentials(Context,
    function { LoginFunc } (const Username, Password, Domain: string): Boolean
    begin
      //The actual user validation
      Result := CredentialList.IsValidCredential(Username, Password, Domain);
    end);
end;
```

Finally I just need to implement  my loginhandler:

```
//This is the "onLogin" event handler.
//This is called durring a login attempt
//The purpose of this event handler are to call tha callBack function with correct information
//and handle the result
procedure TForm1.LoginCredentialEvent(Sender: TObject; Callback: TLoginCredentialService.TLoginEvent; var Success: Boolean);
begin
  //Call the callback
  Callback(Sender, LabeledEdit1.Text, LabeledEdit2.Text, LabeledEdit3.Text, Success);

  //Handle the success.
  if Success then
    Label1.Caption := 'Yes'
  else
    Label1.Caption := 'No';
end;
```

Hope this answers the question.Dont forget to download the complete code [here](http://Borrisholt.dk//TLoginCredentialService.zip)

Comment: I find it a bit strange that you have to resort to using globals in your login handler. I mean the strings user password etc.. You have to pass them from edit controls while you don't have to know your validation function (it's passed back). Strange design..